# Index not created in pdf output, even though idx file is present

Tags: indexing

I have a document that has `\usepackage{makeidx}` and `\makeindex` in the preamble and `\printindex` inside the document body. An `.idx` file is created when I compile, no errors are signalled, still there is no index listing in the PDF document that is produced. There used to be one until all my files were deleted except the `.tex` file, after that I could not get the index to appear in my output.
How can one troubleshoot this thing? I have changed all the `"%bm"` with `"%tm"` wherever I could find it in the build profiles (Tools -> Options -> Clean), as Thorsten Donig suggested on this website (in an answer to another posting regarding problems with the index creation). It did not solve my problem.
I am using the TeXnicCenter editor on Windows XP, with the MiKTeX 2.9 distribution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post. A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: If you look at your output profile (Build --> Define output profiles), is the box "Do not use MakeIndex for this profile" checked? Also, is the path to `makeindex.exe` set correct?

Comment: The "Do not use MakeIndex" box is not checked. But thank you, your second suggestion prompted the fix! As I checked the path to the executable, I found out there are two of them, makeindex.exe and miktex-makeindex.exe! I switched from makeindex.exe to miktex-makeindex.exe and voila! the index appeared in the pdf file!! I have no idea why the first variant stopped working, or maybe something changed for my Adobe on my machine, but now it is fixed, thanks again!

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Write up a little extract regarding the location and where to change the source of `makeindex.exe` in TeCnicCentre as an answer.

Comment: @Werner Done. Diegis: I included your information about the two executables.

Comment: @Diegis Would you consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, thereby marking the question as "solved", and awarding some points to both me and yourself?

Answer (score 9):

During a compile of your file with LaTeX with the `\makeindex` command present, an `.idx` file is produced. However, `\printindex` requires a processed version of `.idx`, or a `.ind` file - the processed version being one that is formatted according to a hierarchy and sorted alphabetically. For this, you require an intermediate step:

1. `latex` or `pdflatex` your `myfile.tex` (this creates `myfile.idx`)
2. `makeindex myfile` (this processes `myfile.idx` into `myfile.ind`)
3. `latex` or `pdflatex` your `myfile.tex` again

Comment: TeXnicCenter should run `makeindex` automatically, so the question is rather why that doesn't happen.

Comment: Yes, I agree! All the necessary files are produced, the idx and ind, and both have content inside (I have checked the files with Notepad). It is driving me crazy!! I will try the oldest trick in the book, re-booting my machine... What is puzzling is that it worked until all files were deleted, other than the tex file. No idea what went wrong... Thank you, Colin.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to check is the settings for the output profile, which is found under Build --> Define output profiles. The box "Do not use MakeIndex for this profile" must *not* be checked, and the path to `makeindex.exe` must be correct.

MikTeX has two different executables `makeindex`, called `makeindex.exe` and `miktex-makeindex.exe`. If the first doesn't work, try the latter.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of a future reader: Check wether you used the file option "aux-directory" somewhere. I made a script

```
xelatex --aux-directory="Help_files" exampleproject
makeindex exampleproject
xelatex --aux-directory="Help_files" exampleproject
xelatex --aux-directory="Help_files" exampleproject
```

(script as well as tex files lie in folder "foo"). It did not work because makeindex searched the idx file in "foo", but xelatex created it in "foo/Help_files". Simply replace `makeindex exampleproject` with `makeindex Help_Files/exampleproject`.