# How to do a simple index?

Tags: indexing

I use

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
```

in the document header. I use

```
COVER, in this page is the `cover\index{ccover}, and the ship\index{sship}
```

is inside that image and finally `\printindex` before `\end{document}`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\pagestyle{fancy} % seleccionamos un estilo

\rhead{TFG - Metaheurística}

\rfoot{Página \thepage}
\cfoot{}
\pagenumbering{gobble} 
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

This document\index{ddocument|(}
COVER, in this page is the cover\index{ccover}, and the ship\index{sship} is inside that image.
\newpage

ABSTRACT
in this page\index{ppage!Parte de arriba} is the upper half
\vspace{15cm}
And after 15 cm, we have page\index{ppage!Parte de abajo}

This document\index{ddocument|(}
\newpage

Starting
jkf jfd sjfj kdjf kdjk sdl kdl fjsdlk jsd fjs ddk jsñkd sdfjg flkjsd kfdl jkldfj lkdfj sdf dfj lkd fgd  fdg gfdfdg dfg fdg f dg fg fdgdf g dfgd ff gs dfgsdf gd f gfd gfd  d\index{Rollo patatero}
\newpage
INDEX
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run `makeindex <file.idx>`?

Comment: @herbert No, I don´t know what is it :-O

Comment: With `imakeidx` package and option `makeindex` the call to `makeindex` is done automatically (given `shell-escape` is enabled)

Comment: @MikaIke: Compile your document with `pdflatex` (or `latex/xelatex`, then run makeindex on the file `*.idx` and recompile again with `pdflatex` (or with ... you know ;-) )

Comment: run `latexmk -pdf <file>` and the script will do it all for you. It often can be run from the menu of your graphical interface like TeXmaker or the like.

Comment: ok, I´ll try but I use winedt, and no any command line. I don´t see clearly the solution.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I can´t use pdflatex, because I have pstricks illustrations., and I have to use LATEX + DVIPS2PDF

Comment: @MikaIke: I also wrote `latex/xelatex` as options ;-)

Comment: YES. SOLVED Thank you @ChristianHupfer and Herbet. I use imakeindex package

Comment: `I sense something; a presence I have not felt since...`  Close - voting is ahead `;-)`. Ok, it is an off-topic comment ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ok, I´ll close, but I still have a problem. In my mwe runs well. but in my big document, I have this problem http://sensa.square7.ch/trtre2.jpg

Comment: SOLVED, the package is makeidx NO makeindex

Comment: @Herbert Feel free to answer or close as off-topic.

Comment: @MikaIke Just to clarify, `makeidx` and `imakeidx` are packages (loaded with `\usepackage`),  whereas `makeindex` is an application (an external tool). With `\usepackage{makeidx}` you have to run `makeindex` yourself (or add it to your build profile.) With `\usepackage{imakeidx}` it tries to run `makeindex` for you using TeX's shell escape (which may or may not be enabled).  Possible duplicate of [Index not created in pdf output, even though idx file is present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36530).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to load the correct package:

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
```

If you use the `latex/pdflatex/xelatex` compiler , compile as follows

```
<compiler> <file.tex>
makeindex <file.idx>
<compiler> <file.tex>
```

If you use the `latex/pdflatex/xelatex` compiler and can enable `shell-escape`, include the `imakeidx` pacakge, and `makeindex` will be called automatically.

If you use `latexmk`

```
latexmk -pdf <file>
```

Finally, check the tool of your LaTeX editor for building the index from the GUI.