# Command to get index pages also in the PDF file

Tags: pdftex, makeindex

Iam using window 7 OS, in the command window, if i run a tex file, i am getting pdf as output, iam using texWorks as converter. but it is not containing the index pages such as list of figures, chapters, sections.

command i used is : "pdflatex filename.tex"

is there any other command to get the index pages also in the pdf file?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Do you add `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` ...?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You need to run the indexing application (`makeindex` or `xindy`). See [Index not created in pdf output, even though idx file is present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36530).